# How do you conference a skype call and a phone call on a Mac?

Tags: skype

We just upgraded to the new Mac 5 and we don't see the conference button anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

via [How do I start a conference call in Skype 5.0 for Mac?](https://support.skype.com/en/faq/FA10809/How-do-I-start-a-conference-call-in-Skype-5-0-for-Mac)

> - In the call window, click the Add Participant button.
>     [image]
> - In the Contact Picker, type the name of the person you wish to add,
>     and then click on their name when it
>     is displayed in the list. This adds
>     them to the list of new participants.
>     Repeat for everyone you want to add to
>     the call.
> - After you have finished selecting people, click Add or press Enter on
>     your keyboard to call the newly added
>     people.

Comment: -1: Link-only answers are not helpful.

Comment: Will this work for phone numbers too? (I don't have skype 5, but I'm tech supporting a friend who does.)